# MDB allow message redelivery

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

we have an application using MDBs on JBoss 7.2.1. The MDBs can occasionally throw a NullPointerException and I would like that the broker attempts to redeliver the message once more after some seconds. This does not seem to happen automatically. 
Is there any setting in the server that allows the message to be redelivered by the MDB automatically ? (The MDB is deployed using the default settings)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bu default JBoss AS 7 (EAP 6 also) will redelivery the message based on the **redelivery-delay** timeout for the number of attempts specified by **max-delivery-attempts**.
The NPE is derived from RuntimeException so the message redelivery will take place. Check out how the exception is handler. If it's thrown by the server, you should be able to see the JMS Broker to re-attempt delivery
See more details on this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/configuring-message-redelivery-on-jboss-wildfly).